# Infer parameter types of chained (optional) function

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a function that takes a config `T` where the methods in that config object have a chained function with a parameter `ctx`. I want to obtain type inference on that `ctx` object according to the shape of the config object `T`.

```
export function slice<
  T extends Record<
    keyof T,
    (state: S, payload?: any) =>
      S | ((ctx: {
        api: {
          [K in keyof T]: (payload: Parameters<T[K]>[1]) => void
        }
      }) => Promise<void>)
  >,
  S extends Record<string, any>
>(
  config: T,
  { initialState }: { initialState: S },
) {
  return {};
}

interface TestState {
  isTest: boolean;
}

const s = slice({
  login: (state: TestState, param: number) => async (ctx) => {
    type T1 = typeof ctx.api; // expecting { login: (state: TestState, param: number) => void, }
  },
},
{ initialState: { isTest: true } });
```

What I'm getting is that the `ctx` object has type `any`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-oCA79SeSNDAoEhDV0+lYkUA)

Comment: Is this the most minimal [mre] you can come up with?  In general trying to do both contextual and generic type inference at the same time is rough and can't always be done properly.  But I can't wade through the example code right now to see if that's what's happening.

Comment: I've updated my question with a stripped-down version of the example. I think it can't go further without losing the error.

Comment: Yeah I'm not seeing a way to have both generic and contextual inferences work, even if we refactor to make the types simpler.  You'll have to cut the Gordian knot either by manually specifying the type parameters [like this](https://tsplay.dev/WzeV3m) or by manually annotating the callback parameters [like this](https://tsplay.dev/mx37KN).  There are relevant github issues like [ms/TS#44999](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44999). Does this address your issue fully? If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, that does address the issue very well. Please do write it up.